# Argument of type '{ id: number; url: string; dataAdded: Date; description: string; isMain: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Photo'

Tags: angularjs, typescript, asp.net-core

I was trying to add the `uploader.onSuccessItem` method but I got an error in the line `this.photos.push(photo);` saying

```
Argument of type '{ id: number; url: string; dataAdded: Date; description: string; isMain: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Photo'.
  Property 'dateAdded' is missing in type '{ id: number; url: string; dataAdded: Date; description: string; isMain: boolean; }' but required in type 'Photo'.ts(2345)
```

this is my `photo-editor-component.ts`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {  FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { Photo } from 'src/app/_models/photo';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/_services/auth.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-photo-editor',
  templateUrl: './photo-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./photo-editor.component.css']
})
export class PhotoEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() photos: Photo[];
  uploader: FileUploader;
  hasBaseDropZoneOver = false;
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeUploader();
  }
  public fileOverBase(e: any): void {
    this.hasBaseDropZoneOver = e;
  }
  initializeUploader()
  {
    this.uploader =  new FileUploader({
      url: this.baseUrl + 'users/' + this.authService.decodedToken.nameid + '/photos',
      authToken: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
      isHTML5: true,
      allowedFileType: ['image'],
      removeAfterUpload: true,
      autoUpload: false,
      maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    });
    this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (file) => {file.withCredentials = false; };
    this.uploader.onSuccessItem = ( item, response , status , Headers) => {
      if ( response ) {
        const res: Photo = JSON.parse(response);
        const photo =  {
          id: res.id,
          url: res.url,
          dataAdded: res.dateAdded,
          description: res.description,
          isMain: res.isMain
        };
        this.photos.push(photo);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

this is my `photo.ts`

```
export interface Photo {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    description: string;
    dateAdded: Date;
    isMain: boolean;
}
```

I am waiting for your help.

Comment: The error refers to "dataAdded" instead of "dateAdded", maybe there is a typo somewhere?

Comment: Is this `dataAdded: res.dateAdded,` supposed to be `dateAdded: res.dateAdded,`?

Comment: thanks, it was a typo, i changed dataAdded to dateAdded thanks a lot. the error panicked me